# Bind - local zone with overriding the remote one

Tags: dns, bind

I have BIND9 server that is serving some local zones (for dev environment). Now I need to be able to **merge** the content of the local zone with the "remote" zone for the same zone:

Local:

```
host1 IN A 10.0.1.100.
host2 IN A 10.0.1.101.
```

Remote

```
www   IN A 1.2.3.4.
mail  IN A 1.2.3.5.
host1 IN A 1.2.3.6.
```

As a result, I need to "merge" local with remote, giving preferences to the local records (hence `host1` will get the address `10.0.1.100`):

```
www   IN A 1.2.3.4.
mail  IN A 1.2.3.5.
host1 IN A 10.0.1.100.
host2 IN A 10.0.1.101.
```

And if I change anything on the remote zone - it should resolve it correctly, like: *if there's no such record in the local zone - try the remote one using `8.8.8.8`*.

Looks like mix of forwarders and local zone.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to use RPZ zones. The response policy feature allows you to override single resource records with bind. This way you can keep the external zone as-is, and only override single records you need to get your dev environment working.

In the `options` section, add:

```
    response-policy { zone "rpz.int.mtak.nl"; };
```

(`rpz.int.mtak.nl` is just used for referencing the RPZ zone, it's not used by end-users).

Add the RPZ zone:

```
zone "rpz.int.mtak.nl" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db/rpz.int.mtak.nl.zone";
    allow-transfer { slaves; };
};
```

And the zonefile:

```
$TTL 60
@            IN    SOA  localhost. root.localhost.  (
                      2014092911
                      3H  ; refresh
                      1H  ; retry
                      1W  ; expiry
                      1H) ; minimum
              IN    NS    localhost.

; Redirect www.twinings.com to www.twitter.com
www.twinings.com    IN CNAME    www.twitter.com.    

; Make google.com unavailable (NXDOMAIN)
google.com          IN CNAME    .

; Rewrite www.superuser.com to 192.0.2.4
www.superuser.com   IN A        192.0.2.4
```

Comment: You probably want to fully qualify those host names, otherwise they will have `$ORIGIN` appended to them. I don't know what that'll be in this particular case, but adding a simple `.` to the end of the names removes the issue entirely. So `www.twinings.com.`, `google.com.` and `www.superuser.com.`. Oh, and I don't think Twitter's web servers will know what `www.twinings.com` is, so you aren't actually redirecting anything...

Comment: You have to make sure you don't fully qualify the RR's, otherwise it will not work. -- Of course, requesting twinings.com at the servers twitter.com doesn't make any sense, but it's just an example, right?